# define the position of the largest even number in a vector with python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can anyone help me with this little problem that I am having in my program with Python 3?

I have to read 10 integers, store them in a vector and determine in which position of the vector is the greatest number read. but  is giving me an  error. this is my code:

```
ma=[1,8,10,12,16,7,4,2,9,5]

for x in range (0,10):
    if (ma[x]%2==0):
        max=str (ma[0])


        for num in str (ma[x]+1):
            if(num>max):
                    max=num
print (max)
```

i will really appreciate your help guys

Comment: *"but is giving me an error"* what exactly is your error?

Comment: it show me  a value however it doesnt show me what im looking for which is the position of the largest even number in the vector.

Comment: and what is the value that it *is* giving you?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
l = [i for i in ma if i%2==0 else np.Nan]
maxIndex = l.index(max(l))
```

This should work if ma is your vector with 10 integers

Comment: it works thank you so much i really appreciate this error was killing me jejej im sorry if im song o excited im just starting programming with python

Comment: If you found this helpful, hit that green check next to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look into the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). Specifically, you might find [the built-in `max()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) useful.

Comment: thank you so much for all you help guys i really appreciate it

Comment: +1 for "built-in max", -1 for incorrect statement re spaces: python ignores spaces between function name and function arguments.